# Using Tasker to know if I'm at work for more than a minute

Tags: android, tasker

I use Tasker's **Wifi Near** option to activate some tasks in my phone when I arrive at my workplace.
My problem is that sometimes I pass by my workplace, with no intention of entering, and the tasks get activated.

Is there a way to make Tasker activate the tasks **IF** I've been near my workplace's wifi spots for more than a minute?

Comment: How are your profiles set up? You may have an additional profile that says 'At work for more than 1 minute', and it activates when your 'Near work' activates. So it can wait for x minutes, check if the 'Near work' is still activated, and only then it activate your 'At work' profile and trigger your tasks.

Comment: How can I make it wait some minutes before verifying?

Comment: There is an action called _Task -> Wait_.

Answer (score 1):

Create three profiles:

**Near Work**

Activates when you are near the work Wifi.

- Enter Task Actions:

  - task -> wait -> 100 milliseconds (actually no actions)

**At work for more than 1 minute**

Activates when 'Near Work' profile is active (State -> Tasker -> Profile Active).

- Enter Task Actions:

  - Task -> Wait -> 1 minute
  - if the 'Near Work' is still active, then call your 'At Work' tasks

Note that the Wifi Near checks frequency is controlled by *Prefs/Monitor/Wifi Scan Seconds* (screen on) and *Prefs/Monitor/Display Off All Checks* (screen of). So you need to consider those values too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution :

**Profile 1** : When Near Work

- Enter Task Actions:

  -- Set Variable %NearWork = true

  -- Set Profile_2 to active
- Exit Task Actions:

  -- Set Variable %NearWork = false *(this resets it for use for next time)*

**Profile 2** : (EVERY 1 min)

- Enter Task Actions :

  -- Set Profile_2 to inactive *(this is the first action that makes sure this profile only runs once after 1 min delay)*

  -- if (%NearWork = true) *This only passes if the Exit Task on Profile 1 hasnt run. Meaning you are still at work after 1 min)

  ---- {{run your actions here. Alternatively call a task which has the actions }}

Comment: I used to work with Variables for these kind of checks, but it turns out to me that having specific, modular Profiles are far more intuitive. You may end up having several, unmaintainable _IF_  statement when new scenarios appear.

Comment: I agree with keeping it modular However i disagree that it should be modular at profile level. Instead I believe keeping it modular at task level and this makes the task akin to a function that can be called in different scenarios/profiles/tasks and that is why i mentioned calling a task with all the actions that need to be done instead of running them within this profile.

Comment: Absolutely. Keeping the tasks and profiles modular is the way to go. I'm just concerned about the use of variables to represent a state, which a profile seems to be more suitable and intuitive in most of the times. I would replace your _NearWork_ variable with a proper profile. I only use variables when there is absolute no way to use a profile (i.e., save the current %TIMES to do some calculations etc).